why Showing Token Expired Message in Console Even If There is New Token generated in Immersive Reader Service which I have deployed in my flask app?
Task:
I am performing deployment of the Azure Immersive Reader service web app locally.
Problem:

On clicking the immersive reader button, it is showing me the following error message.


2. after clicking the ok button it is showing error in my console where I found that it is showing me

So I can't find any solution for it.
So, I am performing the deployment of app using python flask framework. Now, in that I have credential like endpoint and key (I have only access to the endpoint and key) with the use of it I am generating the token which is available for the 10 min and after generating token, with that token and the subdomain available from the endpoint I am launching the immersive reader. This is the whole process I am going through.
What I have:

app.py
-.env
helper.js
index.html

Expected Output:
Whenever I click on the immersive reader button it should enable and read the content on the web page

It is due to the token valid for a short duration, it is very important to check that it is fresh when launching the Immersive Reader.


after clicking the ok button it is showing error in my console where I found that it is showing me.

Then above indicates that the Immersive Reader is not launched properly. It could be due to an incorrect token.

Generate a fresh token each time you launch the Immersive Reader. Check that it is fresh when launching.

helper.js:
document.getElementById('immersiveReaderButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    fetch('/get_token')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.error) {
                console.error('Token generation error:', data.error);
                return;
            }
            const token = data.access_token; // Ensure this matches the structure of the response
            const subdomain = 'your-subdomain'; // Extract subdomain from your endpoint
            const content = document.getElementById('contentToRead').innerText;

            ImmersiveReader.launch({
                token: token,
                subdomain: subdomain,
                content: {
                    title: "Content Title",
                    chunks: [
                        {
                            content: content,
                            lang: "en"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }).then(() => {
                console.log("Immersive Reader launched successfully.");
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error("Error launching Immersive Reader:", error);
            });
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching token:', error));
});

Azure Immersive reader service:

app.py: (Given for reference)
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import requests
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/get_token', methods=['GET'])
def get_token():
    endpoint = os.getenv('ENDPOINT')
    key = os.getenv('KEY')
    headers = {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': key,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    token_url = f'{endpoint}/cognitiveservices/v1.0/token'
    response = requests.post(token_url, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return jsonify({'access_token': response.text})  # Adjust this based on actual token structure
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Failed to generate token'}), 500

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Immersive Reader</title>
    <script src="https://contentstorage.onenote.office.net/onenoteltir/immersive-reader-sdk/v1.0.0/immersive-reader-sdk.js"></script>
    <script src="helper.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Immersive Reader Demo</h1>
    <button id="immersiveReaderButton">Launch Immersive Reader</button>
    <p id="contentToRead">This is some text to be read by the Immersive Reader.</p>
</body>
</html>


Output:


Hello Suresh, i followed the step given by you, it is able get token but showing me the error that "immersive reader sdk is not loaded" even if I have defined it in my index.html file

have you configured all the setup properly? Or try to give some more detail about the issue with snippet.

I have check on postman your URL for getting token is not working and not generating the token.
Instead i use this URL "https://{region}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken" which give me the token

From my side it is working fine! There is a chance of Network latency or delays in the response this can also cause the token to expire before it is used. Check the validity period of the token.

please try your content with the official python code sample here
and also make sure you are getting the token this way:
please let us know if the issue persists

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
